# How to send SOAP request over HTTP use digest authentication HTTP in Java (or C#)?

Tags: java, xml, soap, wsdl, digest-authentication

I  have web service with url is http://192.168.0.10/services/abc?wsdl
This web server using digest authentication with username is admin and password is admin
I want to send request follow to this server

SOAP request XML is SOAP_RQ.XML

```
 <soapenv:Envelope
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:log="LogsGet" xmlns:mal="MalteseGlobal" xmlns:job="JobGlobal">
         <soapenv:Body>
             <log:LogsGetReq Cmd="Start" OpV="01.00.00" Sev="Info to critical"/>
          </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

[image: Picture below description about SOAP communication over HTTP]
My code:

```
 private static SOAPMessage createSOAPRequest(String username, String password) throws Exception {
        MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
        SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();
        // SOAP Envelope
        SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
        envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("log", "LogsGet");
        envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("mal", "MalteseGlobal");
        envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("job", "JobGlobal");
        // SOAP Body
        SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
        SOAPElement soapBodyElem = soapBody.addChildElement("LogsGetReq", "log");
        QName Cmd = new QName("Cmd");
        QName OpV = new QName("OpV");
        QName Sev = new QName("Sev");
        soapBodyElem.addAttribute(Cmd, "Start");
        soapBodyElem.addAttribute(OpV, "01.00.00");
        soapBodyElem.addAttribute(Sev, "Info to critical");
        //SOAP Header
        MimeHeaders hd = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
        hd.addHeader("UsernameToken", username);
        hd.addHeader("PasswordText", password);

        soapMessage.saveChanges();       
        return soapMessage;
    }

public void sendSoapRequest(String url, String username, String password) {
        try {
            // Create SOAP Connection
            SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
            SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

            // Send SOAP Message to SOAP Server         
            SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(createSOAPRequest(username, password, txtArea), url);
            // Process the SOAP Response               
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            soapResponse.writeTo(bos);
            System.out.println();  
            soapConnection.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error occurred while sending SOAP Request to Server");              
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

When I send request, I received a message below:
Bad response: (401Authorization Required)

If I send request use curl tool (http://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.41.0.zip)  with
command line:      curl.exe -X POST http://192.168.0.10/services/Maltese -H "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8" -H "SOAPAction:LogsGet" --digest -u admin:admin -d @SOAP_RQ.xml -v
I received message response OK.

Can any body help me, How to send SOAP request over HTTP use JAVA (or C#)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// I used Apache HttpClient.
// For URL, you need to find end point URL.
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;

// Input parameter
String username = "";
String password = "";
String url = "";

// Variables 
int responseCode = 0;
String errorMessage = "";
String responseContent = "";
String content = ""

HttpResponse response;

try
{
    content = 
        "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:log=\"LogsGet\" xmlns:mal=\"MalteseGlobal\" xmlns:job=\"JobGlobal\">" + 
        "\n  <soapenv:Body>" +
        "\n    <log:LogsGetReq Cmd=\"Start\" OpV=\"01.00.00\" Sev=\"Info to critical\"/>" + 
        "\n  </soapenv:Body>" +
        "\n</soapenv:Envelope>";

    // Create the POST object and add the parameters
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");

    // Enable preemptive authentication within HttpClient so that HttpClient will 
    // send the basic authentications reponse before the server gives an unauthorized reponse. 
    String host = httpPost.getURI().getHost();
    int port = httpPost.getURI().getPort();   
    AuthScope authScope = new AuthScope(host, port);
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials = new     UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password);
    httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(authScope, credentials);   

    StringEntity input = new StringEntity(content);
    input.setContentType("application/json");
    httpPost.setEntity(input);   
    response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

    if (response != null && response.getStatusLine() != null)
    {
        responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        responseContent = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    }

    System.out.println("\n\n-----------------------------");
    System.out.println("\nResponse code: " + responseCode);
    System.out.println("\nResponse content: " + responseContent);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    errorMessage  += "\nUnexpected Exception: " + e.getMessage();
    StringWriter sWriter = new StringWriter();
    PrintWriter pWriter = new PrintWriter(sWriter, true);
    e.printStackTrace(pWriter);
    errorMessage += "\n" + sWriter.getBuffer().toString();

    errorMessage += "\n------------Error Detail------------";
    errorMessage += "\n" + e;
    errorMessage += "\n" + e.getMessage();
    errorMessage += "\n" + e.getLocalizedMessage();
    errorMessage += "\n" + e.getCause();
    errorMessage += "\n" + Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace());
    errorMessage += "\n" + e.printStackTrace();
    errorMessage += "\n------------------------------------";
}
finally
{
    if(response)
    {
        EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());    
    }
}

if(errorMessage != "")
{
    System.out.println("Error: " + errorMessage);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If use C#
I created successful
My code:

```
private  string WebServiceCall(string url)
        {
            try
            {
                Uri myUrl = new Uri(url);
                WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(myUrl);
                HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)webRequest;
                httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
                httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
                httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction: LogsGet");
                httpWebRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;

                //Credentials
                NetworkCredential myNetworkCredential = new NetworkCredential("admin", "admin");
                CredentialCache myCredentialCache = new CredentialCache();
                myCredentialCache.Add(myUrl, "Digest", myNetworkCredential);
                httpWebRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;
                httpWebRequest.Credentials = myNetworkCredential;
                Stream requestStream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream();
                //Create Stream and Complete Request             
                StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(requestStream, Encoding.ASCII);

                StringBuilder soapRequest = new StringBuilder("<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" ");
                soapRequest.Append("xmlns:log=\"LogsGet\" xmlns:mal=\"MalteseGlobal\" xmlns:job=\"JobGlobal\">");
                soapRequest.Append("<soapenv:Body>");
                soapRequest.Append("<log:LogsGetReq Cmd=\"Start\" OpV=\"01.00.00\" Sev=\"Info to critical\"/>");
                soapRequest.Append("</soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>");

                streamWriter.Write(soapRequest.ToString());
                streamWriter.Close();
                //Get the Response    
                txtRequest.Text = soapRequest.ToString();
                HttpWebResponse wr = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
                StreamReader srd = new StreamReader(wr.GetResponseStream());
                string resulXmlFromWebService = srd.ReadToEnd();
                return resulXmlFromWebService;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return e.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Comment: If you can write code use Java, you can post on this toppic.